# Submitting form in asp razor with Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a problem with submitting form in asp razor. Im using Ajax. I have collection and I am making a form for each element in it. I want to pass again an Id of submited element.
Here is my code:

```
@for(int i=0; i < Model.Models.Length; i++)
{

string s = "metriceDiv" + Model.Models[i].Id;
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Bookmark", "Metrice", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Get",
    UpdateTargetId = "metriceDiv" + Model.Models[i].Id,
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{ 
    <div id="@s">
    <br />
    <table>
<tr>
    <th>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Models[i].Id)
            <input type="submit" value="Bookmark"  />
    </th>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

It's only working when I submit first element. Every other element gives me null in model. What can I do to get Id of any element? Can I put this value to the additional field in my model?

Answer (score 0):

try to set one id for all element and check are null Again. your hiddenFor edit with it :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Models[0].Id)
```